# Serialization Overwriting Data

Tags: java, serialization, linked-list

I have a program I'm making for a small business which is implementing serializable on a linkedList to save data. This all works fine, until I have two staff members try and add more data to the list and one ends up overwriting the other.

```
JButton btnSaveClientFile = new JButton("Save Client File");
    btnSaveClientFile.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // add new items to list
            jobList.add(data);
            .
            .
            .

            Controller.saveData();
        }
    });
    btnSaveClientFile.setBounds(10, 229, 148, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnSaveClientFile);
```

This method results in one overwriting the other, so I tried doing it like this

```
    JButton btnSaveClientFile = new JButton("Save Client File");
    btnSaveClientFile.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            Controller.retrieveData();
            // add new items to list
            jobList.add(data);
            .
            .
            .

            Controller.saveData();
        }
    });
    btnSaveClientFile.setBounds(10, 229, 148, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnSaveClientFile);
```

And when I use this one, I get no data added to the list at all. Here are my Serialization methods. This one is used to save my data.

```
    // methods to serialize data
public static void saveData() {
    System.out.println("Saving...");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("Data.bin");
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(myOLL);

        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

And this one is used to collect my data

```
    public static void retrieveData() {
    // Get data from disk
    System.out.println("Loading...");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("Data.bin");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        myOLL = (OrderedLinkedList) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("File cannot be found");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

How do I make it so I can save data to my file from two different computers at a similar time, without one overwriting the other?

Comment: You need synchronization at file-system level.

Answer (score 1):

This is a demo (and not meant to be used in this crude way) how to acquire a lock on file /tmp/data.

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile( "/tmp/data", "rw" );
FileChannel chan = raf.getChannel();
FileLock lock = null;
while( (lock = chan.tryLock() ) == null ){
    System.out.println( "waiting for file" );
    Thread.sleep( 1000 );
}
System.out.println( "using file" );
Thread.sleep( 3000 );
System.out.println( "done" );
lock.release();
```

Clearly, reading a sequential file, mulling over it for some time and then rewriting or not is prohibitive if you require a high level of concurrency. That's why such applications typically use database systems, the client-server paradigm. A free-for-all on the file system isn't tolerable except in rare circumstances. Your organization may be able to assign updates of the data to one person at a time, which would simplify matters.

Answer (score 0):

> add more data to the list and one ends up overwriting the other.

This is how files work by default, in fact the ObjectOutputStream doesn't support an "append" mode.  Once you have closed the stream, you can't alter it.

> How do I make it so I can save data to my file from two different computers at a similar time, without one overwriting the other?

You have two problems here

1. how to write to a file twice without losing information.
2. how to co-ordinate writes between processes without one impacting the other.

For the first part, you need to read the contents of the list first, add the entries you wand to add, and write out the contents again.  OR you can change the file format to one which supports appending.

For the second part, you need to use locking of some kind.  A simple way to do this is to create a lock file.  You can create a second file atomically e.g. `file.lock` and the one which succeeds in creating the file holds the lock, that process alters the file and deletes the lock which finished.  Some care needs to be taken to ensure you always remove the lock.

Another approach is to use file locks. You have to take care not to delete the file in the process however this has the benefit that the OS will clean up the lock if your process dies.

Comment: I had to read it twice, but I still don't see why locking is only required for "2." and not for "1.". If "1." is done by one process, writing a file twice without losing info is no problem; if done by two processes, you are in fact doing "2.". -- Please clarify.

Comment: "Some care...remove the lock": Terminating the Java VM issuing the lock appears to remove the lock, which is not "persisted" in the file system. Of course, holding on to a lock longer than necessary is to be avoided.

Comment: @laune I was suggesting you could use a "lock" file which is simple, but has the problem it is not automatically deleted.  You can lock the file itself, which is harder to implemented, e.g. you can't lock a file before it exists, and you can't see that the file is locked easily, but will work better in the event of a crash.

Comment: Since there is java.nio.channels.FileLock, rolling your own with (perhaps-not-so-portable, maybe-atomic) file system ops is second choice. (I did this, once, 20 years ago, when there was nothing else, and remained, even sporadically, a source of irritation.)